# Adding a space after colon using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to format my page with various labels, colons, and answers. For example:

```
Classes offered: math, English, physics
Total number of students: 30
```

I am using the list item and strong tags for the label portion. So the code looks like this:

```
<li><strong>Total number of students:</strong>30</li>
```

However, this code results in no space between the colon and the answer. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: There's no space in your code. You can literally just put a space in the code before the `</strong>`. You don't need an `&nbsp;` unless you want more than 1 space as the code is automatically trimmed for whitespace when rendered (unless the `white-space` rule is set to `pre`, but you didn't need to know that).

Answer (score 1):

That's simple, just add `&nbsp;` after the colon, like this :

```html
<li><strong>Total number of students: &nbsp;</strong>30</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods, for example using a non breaking space:

```html
<ul>
<li><strong>Total number of students:&nbsp;</strong>30</li>
</ul>
```

But the space is not really part of the semantics of your text so a margin to the right might be more logical:

```css
strong {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
    <li><strong>Total number of students:</strong>30</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself in html needing a space you can always insert `&nbsp;`

In your situation you can add a space, but only one. Additional spaces are ignored.

```html
<li><strong>Total number of students: </strong>30</li>

<li><strong>Total number of students:    </strong>30</li>

<li><strong>Total number of students:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>30</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can of course format your HTML to include the space, including just adding a space or `&nbsp;` inside your `strong` selector.

However if you need to preserve your markup or can't change it, use the CSS `after` pseudo element on your `strong` element:

```
strong::after {
  content: " ";
}
```